React native WebView can't run script tags when injected
I have a problem implementing an SDK inside of react native webview. While sdk.onAddToCard works all fine and I can get the data via onMessage, sdk.setPath does not work at all. I tried many solutions but none of them worked. Should I go Iframe inside of Webview (because that works) or how can I communicate with the view with the help of sdk?


function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  const ref = useRef<WebView>(null);
  const jsObject = `
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.id='initial-script'
            script.src = 'SDK CDN file';
            script.onload = function() {
              sdk.onAddToCart((products)=>{
               window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(products);
              })    
            }
           
            document.body.appendChild(script);
  `;

  const injectAdditionalScript = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const scriptToInject = `
        sdk.setPath("choose-model")
    `;
      ref.current.injectJavaScript(scriptToInject);
    }
  };
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        ref={ref}
        style={{flex: 1}}
        containerStyle={{flex: 1}}
        source={{
          uri: 'http://localhost:4000/vto/makeup',

        }}
        contentMode={'mobile'}
        onMessage={event => console.log(event.nativeEvent.data)}
        injectedJavaScriptForMainFrameOnly={false}
        injectedJavaScript={jsObject}
        sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
        thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        startInLoadingState={true}
      />
      <Button title={'button'} onPress={() => injectAdditionalScript()} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}


export default App;



